# How can you schedule a computer to boot at a specific time?

Tags: boot, scheduling

Usually BIOSes have an option to schedule a time to which to boot at. Is there a Unix/Linux interface to specify the scheduled boot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[NVRAM WakeUp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nvram-wakeup/) claims to do it; I've never tried. It may not work on all BIOSes, and if it fails a likely consequence is to overwrite a different critical setting that could make your computer unbootable, so use with caution.

If you only suspend the computer, [APM tools](http://alumnit.ca/~apenwarr/apmd/) can set a wake-up time with [`apmsleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/apmsleep). I've successfully used my laptop as an alarm clock with this tool. But it can't wake up a powered off computer.

If your computer supports ACPI (all modern ones do), and if ACPI actually works on your OS (that, on the other hand, is not a given), there is a standard interface for specifying a wake-up time. Under Linux, `date -u +%s -d 'tomorrow 6:00' >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` should do the trick. There is a good guide on [ACPI wakeup](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup) on the MythTV wiki.

If you have another powered-on device on the local network, you can send your computer a [wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_LAN) packet. Most modern BIOSes support this (you may need to be enable it in the BIOS settings). The [`wakeonlan`](http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/jpo/software/wakeonlan) utility can send such packets.