# Boot computer on schedule 2 times per weekday

Tags: boot, cron

**My setup:** I use Ubuntu 14.04 to perform a range of tasks. These tasks are performed whenever I execute a bash script. When it has finished the tasks the computer is automatically shut down (I don't want to suspend or hibernate).

**My Question:** What is the most convenient way of scheduling booting my computer? I want the computer to boot 2 times per weekday (let's say 9am and 5pm) and execute my script at startup.

I guess that combining rtcwake and crontab is necessary but I am not sure how to do this properly. I am powering of my computer with a python script but I could also execute rtcwake commands in this script if necessary. Also note that my computer cannot rely on wake-on-LAN.

edit: I have seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5291/how-can-you-schedule-a-computer-to-boot-at-a-specific-time) but it does not address my question. I know how to boot my computer at a specific time. I would like to know how I can schedule my booting time two times a day only on weekdays.

edit: **I have done it myself**. I've written a python script that reads the weekdays, hours and minutes from a csv file and computes the number of seconds until the next entry of the list occurs based on the current time. I feed this number to rtcwake and execute the whole thing with python's subprocess module. I am thus able to boot my computer at arbitrary times if I power off my computer with this script. Unfortunately, this question is marked as duplicate. As long as this remains, I want make an effort to provide details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly against suspend or hibernate, there is no way that I know of for the computer itself to fully power down *and* be able to power up on command that dynamically.

If you have another computer on the network (or certain other devices such as routers with custom firmwares), however, you may be able to schedule [Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) (WoL) to where the second computer wakes up this first computer on any schedule you configure (via CRON on linux, Task Scheduler on Windows, etc). This depends on the first computer having a network card that is capable of WoL, but would allow you specify specific days of the week, specific times of day, multiple times, etc.

Comment: It is definitely not easy. I think I know a way, though. My plan is to let the python script check the day and time to run the rtcwake command accordingly. I should be able to do this with [python subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). I just need to solve the super user privileges but this can be solve with [this gem](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/02/22/raspberry-pi-restart-shutdown-your-pi-from-python-code/). If there is no other good answer, I will let you know about my progress.

Comment: [rtcwake](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake) appears to essentially be suspending the computer for a given amount of time, which you specified you didn't want the computer to do, so I was aiming for a method that would allow *full* power down. If you only care that the computer use less power during that period, then I fully agree that something like rtcwake would be an ideal solution when added at the end of your bash script or to run immediately after the bash script completes.

Comment: Executing `rtcwake -m off -s 100` powers off my computer and boots again in 100 seconds. Are you implying that it's actually not powering off but hibernating or even suspending?